# HTML5 Local Storage, how to pass variables?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Ok, here is my problem. I am writing a Chrome extension, it's almost done, but the problem is, for example:

[Page popup.html]

```
localStorage["code"] = "alert('Hello!');";
```

[File injection.js; which will be called everytime a page is loaded, content script I think]

```
localStorage["code"] = (localStorage["code"] != undefined) ? localStorage["code"] : "alert('Default!');";
eval(localStorage["code"]);
```

I have tried 2 methods, the first thing is to NOT OPEN THE POP UP, so that every page I load would run command alert("Default!"); and it works. Then I tried to load the popup first, and I realize that the variable `localStorage["code"]` is now up to the page I load, not to my extenstion anymore. In a quick explanation, in my extension, `localStorage["code"] == "alert('Hello');";` but in http://google.com `localStorage["code"] == "";` or in http://facebook.com `localStorage["code"] == "";`.

My question is, is there anyway to store localStorage["code"] from popup.html that injection.js can access?

Answer (score 3):

Three are 2 kinds of local storages - one belongs to extension itself (can be accessed only from a background page, popup page or any page bundled into extension package), another one belongs to the site (can be accessed only from a content script).

So if you need to access local storage value that was set in a popup from a content script, you need to send a request to a background page, read the value there, and send it back to a content script. How to do that is explained in [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html) doc.

Comment: background page cannot send a message to popup. Dunno why, but it can't.

Comment: @DataGreed It can't if popup is closed at a moment.

Comment: but is there a way to pass a variable to a closed popup? For example, i select something on the page and then i click popup button and want the popup to recieve selection?

Comment: @DataGreed Instead of pushing data to popup, change your program logic to pull data from popup when the data is needed.

Comment: lolwut, it sounds like "instead of drinking water from glass, change your logic to fill it up"

Comment: @DataGreed no, it sounds like instead of force-feeding someone, put food on the plate and let them eat it when they want.

Comment: then u should review your previous comment, because u made a logical mistake ;)

Comment: @DataGreed I didn't make any mistake, you probably just don't understand the difference between data pushing and data pulling strategies, that's why you are having trouble solving this popup issue in the first place.

Comment: i understand the difference, but read your commment once more

Comment: @DataGreed I said that instead of pushing data from content script to popup, you need to have popup pull data from content script when it needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

Content-Script :

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ action : "getCode" }, function(response) {
    alert(response.getCode);
});
```

Background Page :

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{   
    case "getCode":
        sendResponse({ getCode: localStorage['code'] });
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sindar. You code works fine for me, but I have another problem. I let people change the localStorage["code"] in the options.html page, so whenever they change it, I save it, the browser [exactly the background.html] won't send the update code until the browser is restarted [which means the background.html restarts]. So is their any idea for this problem. And your answer once again works fine for me, just another problem comes up! [x]

Comment: That's because you need to synchronize it ;) Just for the test, put an alert after and before saving you'll see ;)

Comment: I don't get it, so do I just need to put those code in and it auto-synchronize? [x]